# Error 400 Required request body is missing

Tags: angular, typescript, api, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot REST endpoint written in Kotlin as such:

```
@GetMapping(value="/transferDetails")
private fun transferAccountDetails(@RequestBody transferAcctDetails: TransferAccountDetails):results{

    /** Hidden logic*/

    return results(true,"Details Transferred Successfully")
}

//region Data View classes for HTTP response are defined here
data class TransferAccountDetails(val ownerKey: String, val counterPartyKey: String, val acctId: String)
```

What the above endpoint does is merely taking the parameters from the request body and make some changes to the database and eventually return a success message.

Let say I cannot change the behavior or the request type used for this endpoint (e.g. `POST` or `PathVariable`) and that the above script is final and has been tested with Postman and it works.

On the frontend, I am using Angular and sending the request to the above endpoint in my `service` as follows:

```
  processAccountDetailsUrl = 'http://.../api/transferDetails';

  processAccountDetails(ownerKey: string, counterPartyKey: string, acctId: string) {
    this.paramsDict = {
      ownerKey: { ownerKey},
      counterPartyKey: { counterPartyKey},
      acctId: { acctId }
    };

    this.requestOptions = {
      params: new HttpParams(this.paramsDict)
    };

    return this.http.get(this.processAccountDetailsUrl , this.requestOptions);
  }
```

I am getting the following error 400:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-11-29T08:16:52.793+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required request body is missing: private final com.template.webserver.results..."
    "path": "/api/transferAccountDetails"
}
```

Is `requestOptions` not the way to add request body to a `GET` request? If so, what changes should I make to be able to call the REST endpoint and where did it go wrong? Assume that I can only edit the frontend and the backend has been tested to be working and no further changes should be made.

I tried creating an interface in my TS file that has the same variables as the `data class TransferAccountDetails` and tried parsing it like `return this.http.get(this.processAccountDetailsUrl , this.theInterfaceObject);`. This is not working as it is not a type for a `GET` request.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to have a RequestBody on a get request :

[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9927

Comment: Yes, I understand that and have seen the post you have shared. But the scenario is that I cannot change what has been done on the backend. Is there a way to resolve this error for the frontend?

Comment: You can only change the front end not the back end ?

Comment: Yes, hypothetically, if that is the case then what did I do wrong on the angular side (my service.ts)?

Comment: well you can change the request body to requestParameter or pathVariable depending on what it's supposed to do

Comment: I am already using ```requestParameter``` (in the above ```service.ts``` script) isn't it (added ```requestParams``` in ```this.requestOptions```)? I can't use ```pathVariable``` on angular service because the endpoint requires a ```RequestBody``` right?

Comment: yeah right, if you can't change this request body, I'm not sure you will be able to reach your endpoint, maybe you can try to make an ajax call with another library, but   it wouldn't be a good solution